# split, apply and combine on 2 columns of data

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I've got a dataframe consisting of a group and 2 value columns, as such:

```
group  val1  val2
    A     5     3
    A     2     4
    A     3     1
    B     3     6
    B     2     1
    B     0     2
```

I want to work out the number of rows where val1 > val2, split by subset. Initially I hardcoded this per subgroup with:

```
number_a <- nrow(subset(df, group=="A" & val1 > val2))
number_b <- nrow(subset(df, group=="B" & val1 > val2))
```

What's the proper way of automating this? I tried using the `split()` function but I couldn't work out how to pass in both `val1` and `val2` column.

Comment: You want the number of rows, or the rows themselves?

Comment: Sorry yes number of rows, there should be an nrows() wrapping my subset

Comment: In dplyr, I would use `filter(df, val1 > val2) %>% count(group)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straight forward using `data.table`

If you want the number of rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(RowsNum = sum(val1 > val2)), by = group]
#    group RowsNum
# 1:     A       2
# 2:     B       1
```

If you looking for `split`, `apply` combinations in base R, could also try

```
sapply(split(df[-1], df[1]), function(x) sum(x[1] > x[2]))
# A B 
# 2 1
```

Or using `tapply` (also from base R)

```
tapply(with(df, val1 > val2), df[1], sum)
# group
# A B 
# 2 1
```

---

If you want the rows themselves

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[val1 > val2]]
#    group val1 val2
# 1:     A    5    3
# 2:     A    3    1
# 3:     B    2    1
```

Or very simple with base R too

```
df[with(df, val1 > val2), ]
#    group val1 val2
# 1     A    5    3
# 3     A    3    1
# 5     B    2    1
```

Or

```
subset(df, val1 > val2)
#   group val1 val2
# 1     A    5    3
# 3     A    3    1
# 5     B    2    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the base R solutions, I'm trying to understand most of it before moving onto other libraries

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 filter(df, val1 >val2)
 #   group val1 val2
 #1     A    5    3
 #2     A    3    1
 #3     B    2    1
```

If you need the `nrows`

```
 df %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    filter(val1 >val2) %>%
    summarise(RowsNum=n())
  #   group RowsNum
  #1     A       2
  #2     B       1
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(RowsNum = val1 > val2) ~ group, df, sum)
#  group RowsNum
#1     A       2
#2     B       1
```

Comment: It's a piping operator, take a look [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)

Comment: @Stu It chains together multiple operations. Please check the help page of ?'%>%'

Comment: I don't think `group_by(group) %>%` is needed in the first option

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, you are right.  I was thinking about the possible grouping operations downstream.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
data <- data.frame(group,val1,val2)

attach(data)
aggregate(val1~group,data[which(val1 > val2),],length)
```

Comment: I would not recommend to `attach` data